# How to show Histogram axes or frame in v11 Dataset?

Tags: graphics, dataset

Is there a way to show Histogram (and related plots) axes or frames in v11 Dataset?

```
ds = <|"Med" -> <|"dt" -> {48, 13, 0, 1, 0}, 
     "nClicks" -> {10, 3, 1, 2, 1}|>, 
   "Lab" -> <|"dt" -> {13, 9, 51, 10, 13}, 
     "nClicks" -> {5, 4, 15, 4, 5}|>|> // Dataset
```

Then

```
ds[All, All, Histogram[#, Frame -> True] &]
```

[image]

In v10, a usable workaround was to wrap `Framed` (if needed, an invisible one w/ Opacity 0) at the 2nd level, but v11 broke that and instead you get useless `...`

```
ds[All, Framed, Histogram]
```

[image]

Comment: The code `ds[All,Framed,Histogram]` ends up applying the `Framed` function to the row-level association, which looks like `<|"Med" -> {{48, 13, 0, 1, 0}, {10, 3, 1, 2, 1}}, 
 "Lab" -> {{13, 9, 51, 10, 13}, {5, 4, 15, 4, 5}}|>`. Try using `ds[All,All,Histogram/*Framed]` instead.

Answer (score 10):

You can revert back to the old formatting with the undocumented `` Dataset`$UseNewDatasetFormatting ``.

```
Dataset`$UseNewDatasetFormatting = False;
ds[All, All, Pane[Histogram[#], ImageSize -> 200] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]